# Java program to get a part of filename into a collection variable?

Tags: xml, list, filenames

i have several xml files stored in a directory their filenames are like this eg. spring-batch-704.xml , spring-batch-750.xml, spring-batch-786.xml etc..

- How to get only the number in the filename and put into a collection variable(list,array) ----spring-batch-**704**.xml
- Input - many xml files in a folder
- Expected output- list of numbers. 
  for the above example output will be 704 750 786

Comment: Are you asking how to do ls on a directory from Java, or how to parse a string? Or both?

Comment: It is on a directory @doctorlove

Comment: Bad font choice on my part - can you walk a directory in Java?